# cargar fichero html mediante window en js

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un cuadro de dialogo que aparece un texto y dos botones. Como puedo hacer que al darle al boton de aceptar recargue el archivo html en que se encuentra o pueda referenciar un archivo html para que cargue?

```js
var cuadroDialogo = confirm("Que mente mas privilegiada tienes compañer@\n¿Quieres mas?");
                if(cuadroDialogo == true) alert("Me alegro !!");
                else alert("Pues es una pena !!");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// Recargar la página actual
window.location.reload();

// Establece la nueva ubicación de la ventana actual
window.location = "https://www.example.com";

// Establece el nuevo href (URL) para la ventana actual.
window.location.href = "https://www.example.com";

// Asigna una nueva URL a la ventana actual.
window.location.assign("https://www.example.com");

// Reemplaza la ubicación de la ventana actual con la nueva.
window.location.replace("https://www.example.com");

// Establece la ubicación de la ventana actual.
self.location = "https://www.example.com";

// Establece la ubicación de la ventana superior de la ventana actual.
top.location = "https://www.example.com";
```

Fuente: [appendto.com](https://appendto.com/2016/04/javascript-redirect-how-to-redirect-a-web-page-with-javascript/) | [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/location)

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda amigo !!